# Adding valid wildcard SSL certificate to KeyCloak returning 'Illegal base64 character 2d'

Tags: java, encoding, ssl-certificate, keycloak

I am trying to add SSL certificate to my KeyCloak instance. When using self-signed wildcard certificate everything works fine, though when I am using my client valid wildcard certificate I am getting:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d

I am using KeyCloak 18.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, openjdk version 17.0.3.

When trying to validate the certificate I get it is valid. I have tried to update my openjdk version with no results, I have tried to try it against other KeyCloak (17.0.0) versions and it didn't help.
The only relevant results I found relates to the Java version but not connect it to KeyCloak in any way. When looking at the certificate there are no visible illegal characters.
I have also tried to convert the certificate into Base64 just in case, with no help.

My configuration file has nothing unique - it is the basic configuration file with the SSL configuration part aiming at the SSL certificate path.